# Can't override an event handler when changing the argument class

Tags: c#, events, overriding, handler

I'm trying to override an event handler. works fine except when I also want to override the argument class. This is needed for casting to enums.

Code showing the problem

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public class Args : System.EventArgs
    {
        public System.String arg { get; }
        public Args(System.String Iarg)
            : base()
        {
            arg = Iarg;
        }
    }
    public delegate void Handler(Args e);
    public abstract event Handler changed;
}
public class Sub_OK : Base
{
    public override event Handler changed;
}
public class Sub_Not_OK<TEnum> : Base
{
    new public class Args : System.EventArgs
    {
        public TEnum value { get; }
        public Args(TEnum Ivalue) { value = Ivalue; }
    }

    new public delegate void Handler(Args e);
    new public event Handler changed; // Error here
    //public override event Handler changed; // And error here
    //Including the next 2 lines compiles, but changed_2 can't be used in generic code.
    //public event Handler changed_2;
    //public override event Base.Handler changed;
}
```

Have tried misc. combinations of new and override, but can no way make it compile.

Trying this "new public class Args : Base.Args" don't help.

I get these errors:

```
Error CS0534 'Sub_Not_OK<TEnum>' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Base.changed.add'.
Error CS0534 'Sub_Not_OK<TEnum>' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Base.changed.remove'.
```

By the way, I can't understand why i Don't get same errors for Sub_OK, which is probably related to not being able to solve this problem.

Ps. Sorry for bag tagging, don't includes the problem's name.

Comment: `When you inherit from a class in C#, you are required to implement all methods marked as abstract unless your class is itself marked as abstract. Abstract classes are ones that cannot be directly instantiated at runtime because they don't fully implement all of the required methods that the base class(es) say must exist`

Comment: I know that, which is why I don't understand why Sub_OK compiles when Sub_Not_OK wont. Sub_OK does not have any add or remove methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the *main* thing that is confusing you at the moment is that the error messages appear to be saying something that would apply equally to both `Sub_OK` and `Sub_Not_OK<T>`. That is, neither class has a `Base.changed.add` or `Base.changed.remove` method, so both classes should have the same error.

You write "by the way", but it seems like that's really the part you're stuck on at the moment.

The answer is that you're mistaken about `Sub_OK` not having those methods.

*Every* `event` declared in a class *must* have both an `add` and a `remove` method. (This is similar to the `get` and `set` methods for properties.) Your `Base.changed` event has them (which is why they have to be overridden), and your `Sub_OK` class has them (which is why no error is generated).

When you use the `event` keyword in a C# class, you have a couple of options. You can either let the compiler generate the `add` and `remove` methods, or you can implement them yourself. In your `Base` class and your `Sub_OK` class, you did not implement those methods yourself, so the compiler did it for you. In the abstract `Base` class, because your event is declared `abstract`, so too are the `add` and `remove` methods, and they must be overridden in a non-abstract derived class.

In `Sub_OK`, they are. You've declared a non-abstract event which overrides the `Base.changed` event, and you haven't provided explicit `add` and `remove` methods, so the compiler created them for you, and so everything's fine.

In `Sub_Not_OK`, those methods aren't present. They aren't present, because you've used the `new` keyword to *hide* the base class members, and create all new ones. The `Sub_Not_OK.changed` event *is a completely different event* from the one declared in the base class and *does not override* that event. In fact, the new `event` isn't even virtual.

And of course, those `new` members are the *only* members of the `Sub_Not_OK`. Since they are by definition completely new members and not related to the base class members, and since you have *no* other members in the `Sub_Not_OK`, it's also plainly true that you have *nothing* in `Sub_Not_OK` that could override the abstract members of the base class. Including the `Base.changed.add` and `Base.changed.remove` methods. Hence the error messages.

Now, beyond all that, it's not entirely clear what your broader goal is. A good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes examples of how you want to be able to use these classes would help. But, at the end of the day, I think you're not going to be able to do *exactly* what you want.

C# does not provide a way to subclass an event. You've tried to address the warning you get when redeclaring members by adding the `new` keyword, but that doesn't change anything about the declarations. It just makes explicit your choice to hide the base class members. In particular, you're still *hiding* the members, and not overriding them.

If you really insist on a strongly-typed event handler for the derived class, you'll need to provide some mechanism for that. The best way to do it is to simply declare a new event *with a different name*. Hiding base class members is almost always a really bad idea, as it makes the code difficult to understand. Every use of affected members becomes context-dependent, and it's hard for a human being to keep track of the context.

There are things you could do with a virtual event which can be overridden, but it's not clear from your question just how you'd expect to be able to use that. In your code above, assuming you *could* override the base member, deriving the event args class from the base event args class so that the derived `Sub_Not_OK` class could somehow raise the event with that derived event args class, then what? The types would have still to match (i.e. the event would still have to use the base `Handler` delegate type), and so it'd be possible for the event to be raised with the base event args class. A handler expecting the derived event args class would have to have some fallback (such as checking the type and ignoring the event) if the wrong type was passed.

At the end of the day, it'd be better for you to rethink the path you've chosen. Your question doesn't include enough information to know what a better design would be, but it does include enough information to strongly suggest that you need a different, better design.

Comment: Thank for good explanation, understood issues after had read it a few times. Meanwhile I decided to drop the base method (which i only added for being sure sub-classes have this event).
The events are mostly for updating GUI and the controls in the system, knows the event type, so there's no need for a common base event member.